# Partial waves and the velocity expansion of a scattering cross section

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering, dark-matter

I'm confused about the relation between the velocity expansion of a scattering cross section and the angular momentum (partial wave) expansion. For example, for dark matter annihilation, we write

$\sigma v = \sigma_s + \sigma_p v^2 + \cdots$,

where $v$ is the velocity and $\sigma_s$ corresponds to  $s$-wave scattering (orbital angular momentum $\ell =0$) and $\sigma_p$ is the $p$-wave scattering ($\ell =1$).

**Question:**: why does the $v^{2\ell}$ term correspond to initial states in an $\ell$-wave configuration?

---

I understand that in these calculations we treat the scattering states as plane waves, and that these can be expanded as a series of partial waves ($\ell$ eigenstates). And I can see that $\langle \mathbf x | E,\ell,m\rangle \sim j_\ell(kr) \sim k^\ell$. Is there more to this story?